# How does Databricks ingestion time clustering work for read queries?

Tags: query-optimization, databricks, partitioning, data-warehouse

I was reading this document recommanding [using the default ingestion time clustering](https://docs.databricks.com/en/tables/partitions.html#ingestion-time-clustering) rather than partition tables that contains less than a terabyte of data. But it's not convincing enough for me for below quetions:

1. It says do not partition table less than 1TB. But what if I have a fact table that keeps growing, say 3GB per day. Do I partition it or not? It's not 1TB yet as of today, but what happens after a year from now?
2. I'm not sure how ingestion time clustering works for a read query. For example, if I have a fact table partitioned by sale date, then I know exactly which partition to read when I contrain my query to aggregate last year's sale data. How this scenario would work for an ingestion time clustering table though? I probably won't include "ingest time" in my where clause. In this case, how does databricks knows which files to read without going through every single file?

I was not able to find more information about the magic "ingestion time clustering", and feel a bit unsure about it. Thanks in advance for any input!

I googled and tried to find more detailed information about the "ingestion time clustering" technique. But there is very limited information out there.